# Epoch to datetime & timezone conversion request

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I have a dataframe with columns that contain epoch data, I need to convert them into timestamp and then convert the timezone of the timestamp to a different timezone (GMT+3)

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.DataFrame({'data1':['1661191956', '1661191956', '1661191956'], data2':['1661191956', '1661191956', '1661191956'], data3':['1661191956', '1661191956', '1661191956']})`

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Unix time represents seconds UTC; what's the name of the time zone you want to convert to?

Comment: @FObersteiner I tried 
df2["data1"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df2['data1'], unit='s', utc=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
Which has converted the time to utc but I wasn't able to change the timezone afterward.

Comment: `strftime` converts to string. you want to do that later. Use `pd.to_datetime(df["your-col-name"], unit='s', utc=True).dt.tz_convert("your-tz-name")`, see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @FObersteiner

Answer:

```
strftime converts to string. you want to do that later.
```

`Use pd.to_datetime(df["your-col-name"], unit='s', utc=True).dt.tz_convert("your-tz-name")`